# What is the easiest way to make ByteEnum in Python?

Tags: python, enums

## What I need

I am writing a program where I want to define enum with possible interpretation of certain value that is stored one byte. So it is more specific than `IntEnum` as my value must be `int` in range 0x00-0xFF.

There are two types of values in the enum:

- specified by the standard (those I define on my own e.g. 0x00-0x7F)
- user specific (I let the User to define those, e.g. 0x80-0xFF)

Therefore, I am using `aenum` instead of classic `enum` package as my enum might register new members after the program is started.

## What is desired solution

I would like to add some code to `IntEnum` to restrict possible member values, so it has to be both `int` and `0x00 <= value <= 0xFF` or some exception would be raised.
Why? To stop user from defining improper values (e.g. `-1`, `256`, `10.0`) that are not `int` or not in range 0x00-0xFF.

## What are my ideas

I thought to update `__new__` method of `IntEnum`, but its nearly 500 lines long and it is rather hard to understand that. Though, I have notice it has `boundary` parameter. Isn't what I need (lower boundar = 0x00, higher bondary = 0xFF)?

## My code looks like this now

```
from aenum import IntEnum, unique

@unique
class SomeByteEnum(IntEnum):
    FOO = 1
    BAR = 2
    ...
```

After the update, following cases shall raise an exception:

```
@unique
class SomeByteEnum(IntEnum):
    ...  # some magical code here

    INVALID_VALUE = -1  # value is lower than minimal byte value 0x00, exception shall be raised
```

```
from aenum import extend_enum

extend_enum(SomeByteEnum, "INVALID_VALUE", 0x100) # value is greater than max byte value 0xFF, exception shall be raised
```

Comment: I'm not quite following what your requirements are – if the enum should only contain values between 0x00 and 0xff, why not just add no other values? Do you expect user code to change the enum? What would you expect to happen for the values ``0.0``, ``255.9``, or other invalid in-range values? Do the enum values have to be ``int``, or are subclasses viable?

Comment: If you want IntEnums but only between 0x00 and 0xFF inclusive, _how_ do you register new members after the program is started? I mean, once it's populated from 0 to 255 - nothing should be add-able, right?

Comment: I do not register all values between 0x00-0xFF, but only a few of them as there are two groups of values: specified by some standard (those I define) and user specific (those I leave for user). So what I want is to stop user from defining improper one (e.g. `0.0`, `255.9`, `-1`, `266`).

Comment: I have updated the descirption to be more specific. I hope this is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrt:

> I thought to update `__new__` method of `IntEnum`, but its nearly 500 lines long and it is rather hard to understand that.

You will have to update `__new__` but of *your own* enum class, not the actual `IntEnum`.

This is what worked, notes below:

```py
import aenum

@aenum.unique
class SomeByteEnum(aenum.IntEnum):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if not 0 <= value <= 255:
            raise ValueError('Value must be >=0 and <= 255')
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise TypeError('Value must be an int')
        obj = int.__new__(cls, value)
        obj._value_ = value
        return obj
    
    ZEROTH = 0
    FIRST = 1
    SECOND = 2
    THIRD = 3
```

Usage:

```py
>>> from aenum import extend_enum
>>>
>>> list(SomeByteEnum)
[<SomeByteEnum.ZEROTH: 0>, <SomeByteEnum.FIRST: 1>, <SomeByteEnum.SECOND: 2>,
 <SomeByteEnum.THIRD: 3>]
>>>
>>> # allowed:
>>> extend_enum(SomeByteEnum, 'FOURTH', 4)
>>> list(SomeByteEnum)
[<SomeByteEnum.ZEROTH: 0>, <SomeByteEnum.FIRST: 1>, <SomeByteEnum.SECOND: 2>,
 <SomeByteEnum.THIRD: 3>, <SomeByteEnum.FOURTH: 4>]
>>>
>>> # NOT allowed:
>>> extend_enum(SomeByteEnum, 'MeeeeeLION', 1_000_000)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: Value must be >=0 and <= 255
>>>
>>> # NOT allowed:
>>> extend_enum(SomeByteEnum, 'SIXFEETUNDER', -6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: Value must be >=0 and <= 255
>>>
>>> # floats NOT allowed:
>>> extend_enum(SomeByteEnum, '5 point 5', 5.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: Value must be an int
>>>
>>> extend_enum(SomeByteEnum, 'TooTRUE', True)  # True = 1 so is absorbed, no error
cls=<aenum 'SomeByteEnum'> value=True
>>>
>>> # check members
>>> for m in SomeByteEnum:
...     print(m.name, m.value)
...
ZEROTH 0
FIRST 1
SECOND 2
THIRD 3
FOURTH 4
>>>
```

Notes:

1. Specifying a `start=0` like `class SomeByteEnum(aenum.IntEnum, start=0):` breaks how `value` works - extended members cannot be added.
2. Used `aenum=2.2.6`, had some trouble with 3.0.0, like `for m in SomeByteEnum` not showing the added members.

Comment: On your `obj = int.__new__(cls)` you need to specify the value, or each member will be equal to zero -- `obj = int.__new__(cls, value)`.

Comment: @EthanFurman Good catch, I'll edit that. That may have been what gave me trouble with v3.0.0. However, as you can see in the usage output, even without that, the new members do have values; probably due to `obj._value_ = value`.

Comment: They have `._value_` -- try comparing them to actual integers: `SomeByteEnum.FIRST == 1` or `SomeByteEnum.SECOND * 2`.  (Remember to take out the edit before you test! ;)

Comment: @EthanFurman Don't know how/why I didn't test that before. It's also definitely the cause of another bug I had in my trial code before I had posted this answer. Thanks, good sir. (I had it in a `bytes` version of that enum but removed it when I made it just IntEnum.)

Comment: Your solution seems to be complete (contains proper way of adding members as well). Thank you for provding the examples.

Answer (score 2):

`Enum` members are created when the class is created, so your

```
SomeByteEnum.INVALID_VALUE = 0x100
```

is not creating a new member, just an ordinary attribute.  In others words:

```
>>> isinstance(SomeByteEnum.FOO, SomeByteEnum)
True

>>> isinstance(SomeByteEnum.INVALIDVALUE, SomeByteEnum)
False
```

It is possible to have both standard name/values and custom name/values:

```
class SomeByteEnum(IntEnum):
    StdValue1 = 0x01
    StdValue2 = 0x02
    ...
    locals().update(get_user_name_value_pairs())
```

To implement your value restrictions you'll need to write your own `__new__`:

```
    def __new__(cls, value):
        if value < 0x00 or value > 0xff:
            raise ValueError('value must be between 0x00 and 0xff [got %r]' % (value, ))
        member = int.__new__(cls, value)
        member._value_ = value
        return member
```

Note: the above is untested and may contain minor errors.